# How to enable ssl/https on linux tomcat server(works with intern IP)?

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, servlets, ssl

I've got a problem setting up my tomcat on linux for secure connection. My servlets work fine for normal http requests, but when changing the server.xml file to https configuration, the servlet is only addressable through the intern IP. I created a .keystore file in my home directory. The fact, that the https connection(after accepting the certificate) works within the intern network makes me believe it is a router related problem (I opend and forwarded port 8443 on my router).

Thanks for any help!

Server.xml:

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" connectionTimeout="20000" URIEncoding="UTF-8" redirectPort="8443"/>
...
<Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
               maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" 
           keystoreFile="/home/user/.keystore"
           keystorePass="password" />
```

Comment: Provide your code, then we can see what you are doing wrong.

Comment: Which code? I think the servlet code won´t be of any help since it works for http and https local.The server.xml looks like this: `<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" connectionTimeout="20000" URIEncoding="UTF-8" redirectPort="8443"/>
...
<Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
               maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" 
        keystoreFile="/home/user/.keystore"
        keystorePass="password" />`

Comment: don't Post `servel.xml` in comment. add it to your question please.

Comment: Default SSL port is actually 443 not 8443, like default http port is 80 not 8080.  So you probably need to open 443 in your firewall too, and maybe create a connector to redirect 443 to 8443. I've only done SSL in Tomcat by having IIS do it and then forward in to Tomcat, so not 100% sure how you do it on Tomcat alone.

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly the solution for my problem!!